# Refreshing the whole jQuery mobile dialog programatically

Tags: jquery-mobile, backbone.js

I am developing a mobile application with jQuery mobile and backbone. I have backbone model change event function, if any changes in the model, I simply destroy the whole page and recreate with template binding. i use **$('#pageId').page('destroy').page();** which works fine.

I want to do the samething for dialog (just destory the dialog and recreate the dialog and display it). Can you anyone tell me the right method to call.... I just tried with .dialog() but i didn't work.. thanks in advance.

my dialog code.

```
<div data-role="dialog" id="myDialog" data-close-btn="right">
    <div data-role="header"  class="ui-corner-top">
        <h1>dialog</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <form id="myForm">
            <fieldset>
                <label for="fromDate">Date From</label>
                <input id="fromDate" type="date" required placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy">
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <label for="toDate">Date To</label>
                <input id="toDate" type="date" required placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy">
            </fieldset> 
                <input type="submit" value="submit" id="btnSubmit"  data-inline="true" />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Simply use this `$('#myDialog').remove()`. Also use to to remove pages.

Comment: after removing, i tried with .page() & .trigger("create") but nothing worked.

Comment: Please post the code you have tried.